# c# How to make windows restart with confirmation?

Tags: c#, windows, restart

How to make windows restart with confirmation?

I get some code like:

```
   private static void StartShutDown(string param)
    {
        ProcessStartInfo proc = new ProcessStartInfo();
        proc.FileName = "cmd";
        proc.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        proc.Arguments = "/C shutdown " + param;
        Process.Start(proc);
    }

   public static void Restart()
    {
        StartShutDown("-r -t 5");
    }
```

But i have no confirmation like "are you shure to restart?" or so on.

Comment: The shutdown command never asks for confirmation. Therefore you have to build the confirmation into your app.

Answer (score 1):

MatSnow is right, you have to do something like that :

```
private static void StartShutDown(string param)
    {

    if(MessageBox.Show("Confirm shutdown ?","Shutdown ?",MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
     {
        ProcessStartInfo proc = new ProcessStartInfo();
        proc.FileName = "cmd";
        proc.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        proc.Arguments = "/C shutdown " + param;
        Process.Start(proc);
     }




    }

   public static void Restart()
    {
        StartShutDown("-r -t 5");
    }
```